# mongo shell - display raw command sent to server?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am assuming that all commands that a user types into mongo shell are converted into a JSON string before being sent to the mongodb server for processing.

For example, if I send the following **JSON** to the mongodb server, the server will return the document where **companyId equals "12345"**, here is that JSON:

```
{"companyId": "12345"}
```

Is there a way to have **mongo shell display the actual command that is sent to the server** for processing?

P.S.  Just in case you are wondering about my assumption above, I am using the mongo-cxx driver to send commands to the mongodb server.  All commands are formatted and sent to the mongodb server as JSON objects.

Comment: you can have a look at MongoDB profiler, setting the profiler to `2` will collect all operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming that all commands that a user types into mongo shell are converted into a JSON string before being sent to the mongodb server for processing.

Your assumption about the raw commands that get sent to the server for processing is incorrect: the [MongoDB wire protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/) and server-side storage both use [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) (a binary JSON-like serialisation format). JSON is a convenient way to think about the data model (and work with data for human consumption and creation), but BSON is a superset of JSON data types and behaviour.

For example, BSON is an ordered binary data structure (not a dictionary) that does not require field names to be unique. BSON also supports [additional data types](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) such as binary data, 32-bit and 64-bit integers, floats, and Decimals (MongoDB 3.4+). MongoDB drivers take care of serialising data between different representations for convenience (eg language-specific data structures, JSON, or BSON) but if you think of MongoDB as a "BSON database" this may be useful to identify some performance improvements in your approach or explain some otherwise non-obvious behaviour like ordering of keys.

If you really want to see the raw conversation exchanged with a MongoDB deployment, you can use a network packet inspection tool like [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Mongo) that understands the MongoDB wire protocol. However, this is unlikely to be helpful unless you are trying to develop a new driver or debug a very low level server/driver issue.

If you are more interested in logging MongoDB queries or commands as received by the server, you can [adjust the server log level](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/) to include appropriate detail (caveat: additional debug detail can easily be overwhelming) or consider using the [MongoDB profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/). Increased logging or profiling levels should be used with caution in a busy production environment since these can add significant I/O and storage overhead.

> Is there a way to have **mongo shell display the actual command that is sent to the server** for processing?

There isn't a built-in option to display the commands sent to the server, but you can perhaps add more debugging information by customising the `mongo` shell with JavaScript.

The majority of common `mongo` shell helpers are implemented as JavaScript functions that convert the provided arguments into a data structure that can be passed to a [database command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) such as `find` or `aggregate` via [`db.runCommand()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/).  Data in the `mongo` shell is converted from JavaScript to BSON for sending to a MongoDB deployment, and the server response is then converted from BSON to JavaScript for interpretation in the shell. The conversion between BSON and JavaScript is implemented by native C++ methods that are part of the [`mongo` shell source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/shell).

If you want to see how the `mongo` shell implements a specific helper to construct a command such as `db.collection.insertOne()`, try running the command without parentheses: [`db.collection.insertOne`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/a081c83758521e11a5f285541ea9f13928f3de0f/src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js#L235). Most of the shell helper logic will be about parameter validation and returning a result object but at some point the actual server communication will be delegated to a native C++ method which will show as `[native code]` if you try to eval the function in the `mongo` shell without parentheses.

> I am using the mongo-cxx driver to send commands to the mongodb server

By default the C++ driver works directly with BSON data structures and avoids unnecessary serialisation to/from JSON using the [document builder interfaces](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/#create-a-document). However, JSON is a friendlier (but less performant) option if you want to manually create or view data.

For more context on BSON vs JSON, you may also be interested in my answer [Why does MongoDB check for order of keys when matching embedded documents?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/319468/57623) on Software Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: Could you pls answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988073/how-to-match-exact-phrase-with-dynamic-string-in-text-index-mongodb)